# Calling next element in an Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm trying to update the value in xColor, so it can grab a different color from colorPalette. As you can see, colorPalette[xColor].CGColor is doing the work to check what color to use. I'm having trouble trying to update xColor with the swipe gestures, so that it can grab a different element in the array. Any advice would be helpful!

Canvas.swift:

```
    var xColor = 0
    var colorPalette = [UIColor.blueColor(), UIColor.yellowColor(), UIColor.redColor(), UIColor.redColor()]

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        let color = colorPalette[xColor].CGColor
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color)
        let rect = CGRect(x: x - r, y: y - r, width: 2 * r, height: 2 * r)
        CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rect)
}
```

ViewController.swift:

```
func handleSwipes(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

    let cv = CanvasView()

    if (sender.direction == .Left) {
        cv.xColor--
        print("Swipe left!")
    }

    if (sender.direction == .Right) {
        cv.xColor++
        print("Swipe right!")
    }
    print(cv.xColor)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code. The first is this line:

```
let cv = CanvasView()
```

That creates a *new* CanvasView, but that new CanvasView is a different one from the *old* CanvasView that's already showing in the interface. Unfortunately, that old CanvasView is the one you need to talk to!

The second problem, once you're talking to the old CanvasView, is that you are failing to tell it that it needs redrawing. You need to send it the `setNeedsDisplay` message.

Comment: Of course, yet another issue is that if the user keeps swiping in the same direction, the app will crash. But you will have to cross that bridge when you come to it.

Comment: Ok. Creating a new CanvasView is bad. What is the better approach for the two to interact with each other?